# How can I use the plugin configuration in a Shopware 6 administration plugin?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Is it possible to add a plugin configuration to an administration plugin and use it in a vue component or a corresponding twig template?
In the documentation I cannot find something about it. I have tried to use it in my template file like this `{{ config('pluginName.config.inputFieldName') }}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `systemConfigApiService` to fetch config values in Vue.js components:

```js
Component.register('my-custom-component', {
    template,

    inject: ['systemConfigApiService'],

    methods: {
        async getPluginConfig() {
            const response = await this.systemConfigApiService.getValues('YourPluginName.config', salesChannelId);
            const inputFieldName = response['YourPluginName.config.inputFieldName'];
            // ...
        },
    }
}
```

The sales channel id is optional. If omitted the fallback value for all sales channels will be given.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. You have helped me a lot however I have to get the value of the input field with
`const inputFieldName = response['pluginName.config.inputFieldName'];`